# Stop toggled / hidden objects from moving

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm writing a shiny app where I have two columns with valueBoxes. I'd like the user to be able to toggle certain boxes to make the UI less cluttered. The problem is that the boxes are grouped by row and using `shinyjs::toggle()` doesn't only hide the box in question, but removes it from the UI and moves the box underneath it up top. This means that now two boxes from different rows (and thus different groups) are next to each other, which gives the user wrong information.

Is there a way to make it so that when hiding a box some white space of the same size remains instead of moving the lower box up top?

I've tried placing the boxes in their own fluidrows or fixedrows, but this did not have the desired effect.

```
# Example App

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

## UI ##

ui <- dashboardPage(

  skin = "black",
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Template"
    ),

  dashboardSidebar(
    actionButton("toggle_btn", "Toggle!")
  ),

  dashboardBody(

    useShinyjs(),

    fluidRow(
      column(width = 4,
             valueBoxOutput("box1", width = 12),
             valueBoxOutput("box3", width = 12)), 
      column(width = 4,
             valueBoxOutput("box2", width = 12),
             valueBoxOutput("box4", width = 12))
    )
  )
)

## Server ##

server <- function(input, output) { 

  output$box1 <- renderValueBox({

    valueBox(value = 1,
             subtitle = "Row 1, Box 1")
  })

  output$box2 <- renderValueBox({

    valueBox(value = 2,
             subtitle = "Row 1, Box 2")
  })

  output$box3 <- renderValueBox({

    valueBox(value = 1,
             subtitle = "Row 2, Box 3")
  })

  output$box4 <- renderValueBox({

    valueBox(value = 2,
            subtitle = "Row 2, Box 4")
  })

  observeEvent(input$toggle_btn, {

    toggle("box2",
           anim = "TRUE")
  })

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see in my example up top when clicking "Toggle!" Box 4 moves up to the position of Box 2, which I'd like to stop it from doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding fluidRows is the right approach (one fluidRow for each row of valueBoxes).
Please see the following:

```
# Example App

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

## UI ##

ui <- dashboardPage(

    skin = "black",
    dashboardHeader(
        title = "Template"
    ),

    dashboardSidebar(
        actionButton("toggle_btn", "Toggle!")
    ),

    dashboardBody(

        useShinyjs(),

        fluidRow(
            column(width = 4,
                   valueBoxOutput("box1", width = 12)), 
            column(width = 4,
                   valueBoxOutput("box2", width = 12))
        ),
        fluidRow(
            column(width = 4,
                   valueBoxOutput("box3", width = 12)), 
            column(width = 4,
                   valueBoxOutput("box4", width = 12))
        )
    )
)

## Server ##

server <- function(input, output) { 

    output$box1 <- renderValueBox({

        valueBox(value = 1,
                 subtitle = "Row 1, Box 1")
    })

    output$box2 <- renderValueBox({

        valueBox(value = 2,
                 subtitle = "Row 1, Box 2")
    })

    output$box3 <- renderValueBox({

        valueBox(value = 1,
                 subtitle = "Row 2, Box 3")
    })

    output$box4 <- renderValueBox({

        valueBox(value = 2,
                 subtitle = "Row 2, Box 4")
    })

    observeEvent(input$toggle_btn, {

        toggle("box2",
               anim = "TRUE")
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thank you, I tried wrapping the valueBoxOutputs in fluidRows instead of the columns, which works perfectly!